# Bibtex does not work properly "There were undefined references"

Tags: bibtex

I am new to Latex and I try to include references in my document:

I use Texmaker and I export the `.bib` file out of Mendeley.

The file `test.tex` looks like the following:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}


\bibliography{test}
\bibliographystyle{plane} 

\section{test}

test 
\cite{Ref1} 
\end{document}
```

`test.bib` looks like the following:

```
@article{Ref1,
author = {test,1},
number = {5},
pages = {1--16},
title = {{Journal ∗}},
volume = {16},
year = {2006}
}
```

Everything is in the same folder, I tried to compile it twice - I tried to change the `bibliographystyle`, etc. nothing works.
Via autocomplete Texmaker suggest me `Ref1`.

> Error: "Citation "Ref1" on page1 undefined.

Hopefully someone can help me!

Comment: If i run: PDFLatex +Bib(la)tex + PdfLatex(x2)+showPDF it works --> I read that "PdfLatex + show PDF (x2) should be enough?

Comment: where did you read pdflatex should be enough? As you found,  you need to use bibtex to generate the bibliography (biblatex is not involved in this document)

Comment: A better duplicate might be [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/106162)